# Magento2- Email template not being translated

Tags: magento2, email-templates, localisation, email-translation

I have created a custom email template, all works well everything is shown, except when I use the trans dictionary to translate a string from English to German, the translation does not seem to work.

I have provided a `de_DE.csv` file but still the text it not being translated. `Cleared cache`, `reindexed`.

Answer (score 4):

**Magento 2 Translation in Custom Email Template**
**For Example:**

```
{{trans "Shipping Info"}}
```

First, create a CSV file in your theme with the name **de_DE.csv**

```
app/design/frontend/[Your_Vendor]/[Your_Theme]/i18n/de_DE.csv
```

Add your English and DE translation text in the double quote like below:

**Use for Email:**

> "Shipping Info","Lieferadresse",module,Magento_Email

**Use for the Whole website:**

> "Shipping Info","Lieferadresse"

Comment: very nice explanation thanks @Vikram Kumar

Comment: welcome @NavinBhudiya

Answer (score 0):

it's mistake, used `:` instead of `,` in the csv file.

Answer (score 0):

For Email template translate string in m2 you need to wirte code like this.

{{trans "%items are shipping today." items=shipment.getItemCount}}

and when you check in browser, you need to clear cache and local storage from Broswer.
http://prntscr.com/r02pu4